# tikz-network and Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to draw some rooted tree diagrams using the tikz-network package in Overleaf. Overleaf is supposed to an implementation of Tex Live 2019, which has tikz-network pre-installed, but it does not compile consistently.

The problem seems to be that sometimes Overleaf recognizes the tikz-network package and sometimes it doesn't. Let's call it "intermittent compliation". Any work around ideas to get past this? Minimum working example is below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

\Vertex[y=0,x=0,size=0.2,shape=rectangle]{E}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's rather strange that this happens intermittently. Maybe you are switching TeX Live versions by accident between runs (see https://www.overleaf.com/blog/new-feature-select-your-tex-live-compiler-version)? Otherwise, as a sort of fail-safe, you could just add the `.sty` file of the package to your project files, then it will always find the package (download from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-network). But that should not be necessary if you configure Overleaf to use TeX Live 2019.

Comment: Thank you. I added the *.sty file to the project but it still wouldn’t compile consistently. It’s absolutely bizarre. I’ve decided to abandon tiki-network for now and simply use tikz. I like tikz-network because I can build basic graphs quicker, but it’s a bit inflexible if you want anything special. With tikz, diagrams will take a little longer, but I’ll have more control over the environment.